# Zero coupon bonds

Tags: spot-rate

Assume the zero-coupon bonds from 1 year to 4 years are all available, and the current 1-year, 2-year, 3-year and 4-year spot rates are 4%, 5%, 6% and 7% accordingly. Interest rates are annually compounded. You want to lock in a 1-year interest rate beginning in 3 years, by using some of the zero-coupon bonds above.

Question: ) Which zero-coupon bonds would you use?

And what is the locked-in 1-year rate beginning in 3 years?

Comment: Hi user3238961, welcome to Quant.SE! This seems to be copied homework which we generally do not allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for the forward rates between 3y and 4y. I don't want to tell you the answer because it's something that you should attempt. Please read the section on forward rates and how to get the implied interest rate from a zero coupon bond.